# Angular routing, is necessary to have a router-outlet in the parent component when I'm using child routes?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm working on a SPA using angular 9 and I want to have many components to have `/admin` as a parent route.
I have the following routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminHomeComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'platforms',
            component: PlatformListComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'platform/:id',
            component: PlatformCrudComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'projects',
            component: ProjectListComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'project/:id',
            component: ProjectCrudComponent
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

At the moment `AdminHomeComponent` template contains only the router outlet and two links for `platforms` and `projects`

```
<a [routerLink]="['platforms']">Platforms</a>
<a [routerLink]="['projects']">Projects</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Do I really need to have `router-outlet` in `AdminHomeComponent` or I can just use the following route configuration and remove `<router-outlet>` from `AdminHomeComponent`?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/admin',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    // component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminHomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/platforms',
    component: PlatformListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/platform/:id',
    component: PlatformCrudComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/projects',
    component: ProjectListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/project/:id',
    component: ProjectCrudComponent
  },
];
```

`AdminHomeComponent` Is used at the moment only just to show those 2 links I mentioned before

Which is the correct approach?

With the first one is clear that is nested and I can add more components in the future on `AdminHomeComponent`
With the second one, the routing object is more "flat".

I really care about having an easy to understand code for my colleagues and I Want to follow the best possible practice.

Comment: for each child component routing you need one `<router-outlet>`. and order is maintain by it. If you need to component to load parrellaly then you need secondary router-outlet..